# Triggering datepicker from function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, pickadate

I use a `pickadate.js` plugin.

What i would like to do is to trigger a date container after checkbox is checked, but it somehow doesn't work. I assume it has to do something with out of the scope variables since it works just fine outside the checkbox event function.

**Official documentation:**

See [here](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api.htm) and [also here](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api.htm#method-open-close)

**JS:**

```
var pick = $('#chosen').pickadate({format:'dd.mm.yyyy'});
var picker = pick.pickadate('picker');
//picker.open();
// it works here

$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {

        picker.open();
        // it doesnt work here
        event.stopPropagation();

    console.log('checkbox triggers!');

    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ny501uvt/)**

Comment: Grab the pertinent code to reproduce the problem from the `jsFiddle` and put it in the question.

Comment: @MelanciaUK There was jsfiddle in my question all the time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with `click`.  (like `(.on("event", fn))`)

```
$(":checkbox").on('click', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        picker.open();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xLpjz62/)**

Answer (score 1):

I used [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method and now I think it works as intended:

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", function(){

    $(":checkbox").trigger("change");

} );
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/ny501uvt/2/)